# Activity to be displayed even when phone is in locked mode

Tags: android, dialog, themes, locked

My Question is similar to this one
[How can I wake an android device up and skip the screenlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315433/how-can-i-wake-an-android-device-up-and-skip-the-screenlock/9554312#9554312)

I want to display a dialogue box from broadcast receiver, but Android API is not allowing me to do that therefore I am using starting an activity from there and changing the theme of this activity to Theme.

Now I want this activity to be displayed even when phone is in locked mode/ sleep mode.

Screen I am able to turn on bu using below flags but Key Guard (Non Secured) I have to  unlock manually. I am not able to see my window over locked screen.

The difference is that I am not using a full screen Activity i.e.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog
```

in my code I am using

```
Window w = getWindow();
w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | 
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | 
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't succeed in achieving this feature by using these Flags, but I did succeed by using the [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) and  [KeyguardLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html). Below is what I do:

```
public class DismissLock extends Activity {

PowerManager pm;
WakeLock wl;
KeyguardManager km;
KeyguardLock kl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("INFO", "onCreate() in DismissLock");
    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    km=(KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    kl=km.newKeyguardLock("INFO");
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP|PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
    wl.acquire(); //wake up the screen
    kl.disableKeyguard();// dismiss the keyguard

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    wl.release(); //when the activiy pauses, we should realse the wakelock
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    wl.acquire();//must call this!
}

}
```

Of course, you still need to declare the permission in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Comment: kl=km.newKeyguardLock("INFO");
method has been deprecated since API level 13 :(
Any idea on how to deactivate keylock in a Dialog themed activity ?

Comment: nice and simple solution.